# os.path.split(path) is replacing numbers with letters. Help me prevent that

Tags: python

I am using the os module to manipulate some files but have run into an issue. The module appears to be replacing all the strings of 106 with an 'f'.

```py
import os
k = "R:\106xx  2300 Delaware\10628\10628-001\F5 - Drawings and Specifications\DOC\Fire Marshal Wet Signed"
parts = os.path.split(k)
print(parts)
```

I was hoping for something like

(R:\106xx  2300 Delaware\10628\10628-001\F5 - Drawings and Specifications\DOC\, "Fire Marshal Wet Signed")

instead the output is:

('R:Fxx  2300 DelawareF28F28-001\F5 - Drawings and Specifications\DOC', 'Fire Marshal Wet Signed')

where did the 'F's come from? How do I avoid this?

Edit:
[Additional evidence of this behavior](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uoJis.png)

Comment: `\106` is not what you think it is in a Python string. (Nothing at all to do with `os.path.split()`; the string has the wrong characters from the moment it's first instantiated).

Comment: Use forward slashes instead of backslashes, **or** use raw strings, **or** double up your backslashes so they're literal.

Comment: Thanks for prompt reply.